# Problems with Core Plot Graph on device but not on simulator

Tags: ios, iphone, core-plot

I'm trying to use Core Plot to create a graph of three investment scenarios on an iPad.

I'm using Xcode 5, an iPad 4, and iOS 7.

The basic premise is that the user enters the initial investment and interest rate for three different investments and upon clicking a button, a second view is displayed that shows a Core Plot scatter plot representation of each scenario on the same plot space.

My problem is that when I run the application on my iPad (the actual device), the resulting graph only has plots that are equal to y = 0 (this is just what is displayed, I can't post pictures due to a need for a higher reputation with stack overflow)

However, in my iPad simulator in Xcode the graph appears properly, with the equations that I have set up using the data that was input from the initial data view.

I have two UIViews with two separate view controllers. One for my data, and one for my graph display. 
My code is as following:

DataViewController.h

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@interface DataViewController : UIViewController

@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UITextField *principalOneText;
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UITextField *rateOneText;
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UITextField *principalTwoText;
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UITextField *rateTwoText;
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UITextField *principalThreeText;
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UITextField *rateThreeText;





@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIButton *ViewGraphButton;



- (IBAction)HideKeyboard:(id)sender;


@end
```

and DataViewController.m

```
#import "DataViewController.h"

@interface DataViewController ()

@end

@implementation DataViewController

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
}

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning
{
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

- (IBAction)HideKeyboard:(id)sender {
    [self.principalOneText resignFirstResponder];
    [self.rateOneText resignFirstResponder];
    [self.principalTwoText resignFirstResponder];
    [self.rateTwoText resignFirstResponder];
    [self.principalThreeText resignFirstResponder];
    [self.rateThreeText resignFirstResponder];

}
@end
```

GraphViewController.h

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
#import "CorePlot-CocoaTouch.h"
#import "DataViewController.h"
#import <QuartzCore/QuartzCore.h>


@interface GraphViewController : UIViewController <CPTPlotDataSource>

@property (weak, nonatomic) NSString *principalOne;
@property (weak, nonatomic) NSString *rateOne;
@property (weak, nonatomic) NSString *principalTwo;
@property (weak, nonatomic) NSString *rateTwo;
@property (weak, nonatomic) NSString *principalThree;
@property (weak, nonatomic) NSString *rateThree;

- (IBAction)foundSwipe:(id)sender;

@end
```

and GraphViewController.m

```
#import "GraphViewController.h"

@interface GraphViewController ()

@end

@implementation GraphViewController

- (id)initWithNibName:(NSString *)nibNameOrNil bundle:(NSBundle *)nibBundleOrNil
{
    self = [super initWithNibName:nibNameOrNil bundle:nibBundleOrNil];
    if (self) {
        // Custom initialization
    }
    return self;
}

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Transfer values from text boxes in Data Scene to the data holders in Graph Scene
    self.principalOne = ((DataViewController *)self.presentingViewController).principalOneText.text;
    self.rateOne = ((DataViewController *)self.presentingViewController).rateOneText.text;
    self.principalTwo= ((DataViewController *)self.presentingViewController).principalTwoText.text;
    self.rateTwo = ((DataViewController *)self.presentingViewController).rateTwoText.text;
    self.principalThree = ((DataViewController *)self.presentingViewController).principalThreeText.text;
    self.rateThree = ((DataViewController *)self.presentingViewController).rateThreeText.text;

    //create graph upon loading
    //initialise the host-view
    CPTGraphHostingView *hostView = [[CPTGraphHostingView alloc] initWithFrame:self.view.frame];
    [self.view addSubview:hostView];

    //initialize the graph
    CPTXYGraph *graph = [[CPTXYGraph alloc] initWithFrame:self.view.bounds];
    hostView.hostedGraph = graph;
    graph.paddingTop = 25.0f;

    //initialize the plot space
    CPTXYPlotSpace *plotSpace = (CPTXYPlotSpace*) graph.defaultPlotSpace;
    //[plotSpace setXRange:[CPTPlotRange plotRangeWithLocation:CPTDecimalFromFloat(0) length:CPTDecimalFromFloat(16)]];
    //[plotSpace setYRange:[CPTPlotRange plotRangeWithLocation:CPTDecimalFromFloat(80) length:CPTDecimalFromFloat(140)]];


    //Initialize the plots (1,2, and 3)
    CPTScatterPlot *plot1 = [[CPTScatterPlot alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectZero];
    plot1.identifier = @"Investment #1";
    CPTColor *plot1Color = [CPTColor redColor];

    CPTScatterPlot *plot2 = [[CPTScatterPlot alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectZero];
    plot2.identifier = @"Investment #2";
    CPTColor *plot2Color = [CPTColor blueColor];

    CPTScatterPlot *plot3 = [[CPTScatterPlot alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectZero];
    plot3.identifier = @"Investment #3";
    CPTColor *plot3Color = [CPTColor greenColor];

    //plot 4 is a way to make sure that the automatic ranges include y=0
    CPTScatterPlot *plot4 = [[CPTScatterPlot alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectZero];
    plot4.identifier  = @"Placeholder";

    //define the datasource
    plot1.dataSource = self;
    plot2.dataSource = self;
    plot3.dataSource = self;
    plot4.dataSource = self;

    //Combine elements with the graph method call
    [graph addPlot:plot1 toPlotSpace:graph.defaultPlotSpace];
    [graph addPlot:plot2 toPlotSpace:graph.defaultPlotSpace];
    [graph addPlot:plot3 toPlotSpace:graph.defaultPlotSpace];
    [graph addPlot:plot4 toPlotSpace:graph.defaultPlotSpace];





    //graph title and theme setup
    //graph.title = @"Future Values";
    //graph.titlePlotAreaFrameAnchor = CPTRectAnchorTop;
    CPTTheme *selectedTheme = [CPTTheme themeNamed:kCPTDarkGradientTheme];
    [graph applyTheme:selectedTheme];

    //auto-formats the ranges of the x and y coordinates depending on the data used

    [plotSpace scaleToFitPlots:[NSArray arrayWithObjects:plot1, plot2, plot3, plot4, Nil]];
    CPTMutablePlotRange *xRange = [plotSpace.xRange mutableCopy];
    [xRange expandRangeByFactor:CPTDecimalFromCGFloat(1.1f)];
    plotSpace.xRange = xRange;
    CPTMutablePlotRange *yRange = [plotSpace.yRange mutableCopy];
    [yRange expandRangeByFactor:CPTDecimalFromCGFloat(1.1f)];
    plotSpace.yRange = yRange;

    //Styles and symbols
    //plot1
    CPTMutableLineStyle *plot1LineStyle = [plot1.dataLineStyle mutableCopy];
    plot1LineStyle.lineWidth = 2.5;
    plot1LineStyle.lineColor = plot1Color;
    plot1.dataLineStyle = plot1LineStyle;
    CPTMutableLineStyle *plot1SymbolLineStyle = [CPTMutableLineStyle lineStyle];
    plot1LineStyle.lineColor = plot1Color;
    CPTPlotSymbol *plot1Symbol = [CPTPlotSymbol ellipsePlotSymbol];
    plot1Symbol.fill = [CPTFill fillWithColor:plot1Color];
    plot1Symbol.lineStyle = plot1SymbolLineStyle;
    plot1Symbol.size = CGSizeMake(6.0f, 6.0f);
    plot1.plotSymbol = plot1Symbol;

    //plot2 style
    CPTMutableLineStyle *plot2LineStyle = [plot2.dataLineStyle mutableCopy];
    plot2LineStyle.lineWidth = 1.0;
    plot2LineStyle.lineColor = plot2Color;
    plot2.dataLineStyle = plot2LineStyle;
    CPTMutableLineStyle *plot2SymbolLineStyle = [CPTMutableLineStyle lineStyle];
    plot2SymbolLineStyle.lineColor = plot2Color;
    CPTPlotSymbol *plot2Symbol = [CPTPlotSymbol starPlotSymbol];
    plot2Symbol.fill = [CPTFill fillWithColor:plot2Color];
    plot2Symbol.lineStyle = plot2SymbolLineStyle;
    plot2Symbol.size = CGSizeMake(6.0f, 6.0f);
    plot2.plotSymbol = plot2Symbol;

    //plot3 style
    CPTMutableLineStyle *plot3LineStyle = [plot3.dataLineStyle mutableCopy];
    plot3LineStyle.lineWidth = 2.0;
    plot3LineStyle.lineColor = plot3Color;
    plot3.dataLineStyle = plot3LineStyle;
    CPTMutableLineStyle *plot3SymbolLineStyle = [CPTMutableLineStyle lineStyle];
    plot3SymbolLineStyle.lineColor = plot3Color;
    CPTPlotSymbol *plot3Symbol = [CPTPlotSymbol diamondPlotSymbol];
    plot3Symbol.fill = [CPTFill fillWithColor:plot3Color];
    plot3Symbol.lineStyle = plot3SymbolLineStyle;
    plot3Symbol.size = CGSizeMake(6.0f, 6.0f);
    plot3.plotSymbol = plot3Symbol;

    //axis styles and setup
    CPTMutableTextStyle *axisTitleStyle = [CPTMutableTextStyle textStyle];
    axisTitleStyle.color = [CPTColor whiteColor];
    axisTitleStyle.fontName = @"Helvetica-Bold";
    axisTitleStyle.fontSize = 12.0f;
    CPTMutableLineStyle *axisLineStyle = [CPTMutableLineStyle lineStyle];
    axisLineStyle.lineWidth = 2.0f;
    axisLineStyle.lineColor = [CPTColor whiteColor];
    CPTMutableTextStyle *axisTextStyle = [[CPTMutableTextStyle alloc] init];
    axisTextStyle.color = [CPTColor whiteColor];
    axisTextStyle.fontName = @"Helvetica-Bold";
    axisTextStyle.fontSize = 11.0f;
    CPTMutableLineStyle *tickLineStyle = [CPTMutableLineStyle lineStyle];
    tickLineStyle.lineColor = [CPTColor whiteColor];
    tickLineStyle.lineWidth = 2.0f;
    CPTMutableLineStyle *gridLineStyle = [CPTMutableLineStyle lineStyle];
    tickLineStyle.lineColor = [CPTColor blackColor];
    tickLineStyle.lineWidth = 1.0f;

    //x axis setup
    CPTXYAxisSet *axisSet = (CPTXYAxisSet *) hostView.hostedGraph.axisSet;
    CPTAxis *x = axisSet.xAxis;
    x.title = @"Number of Years";
    x.titleTextStyle = axisTitleStyle;
    x.titleOffset = 15.0f;
    x.axisLineStyle = axisLineStyle;
    x.labelingPolicy = CPTAxisLabelingPolicyAutomatic;
    x.labelTextStyle = axisTextStyle;
    x.preferredNumberOfMajorTicks = 15;
    x.majorTickLineStyle = axisLineStyle;
    x.majorTickLength = 4.0f;
    x.tickDirection = CPTSignNegative;

    //y axis setup
    CPTAxis *y = axisSet.yAxis;
    y.title = @"Value";
    y.titleTextStyle = axisTitleStyle;
    y.titleOffset = -20.0f;
    y.axisLineStyle = axisLineStyle;
    y.majorGridLineStyle = gridLineStyle;
    y.labelingPolicy = CPTAxisLabelingPolicyAutomatic;
    y.labelTextStyle = axisTextStyle;
    y.labelOffset = 16.0f;
    y.majorTickLineStyle = axisLineStyle;
    y.preferredNumberOfMajorTicks = 10;
    y.majorTickLength = 4.0f;
    y.minorTickLength = 2.0f;
    y.tickDirection = CPTSignPositive;

    //create a legend
    graph.legend = [CPTLegend legendWithGraph:graph];
    graph.legendAnchor = CPTRectAnchorTop;
    graph.legend.fill = [CPTFill fillWithColor:[CPTColor lightGrayColor]];
    graph.legendDisplacement = CGPointMake(-200.0f, -50.0f);







}

-(NSUInteger) numberOfRecordsForPlot:(CPTPlot *)plot
{
    return 15;
}
-(NSNumber *) numberForPlot:(CPTPlot *)plot field:(NSUInteger)fieldEnum recordIndex:(NSUInteger)idx
{
    int x = idx;
    float principal1 = [self.principalOne floatValue];
    float interest1 = [self.rateOne floatValue]/100;
    float power1 = powf((1+(interest1)), x);

    float principal2 = [self.principalTwo floatValue];
    float interest2 = [self.rateTwo floatValue]/100;
    float power2 = powf((1+(interest2)),x);

    float principal3 = [self.principalThree floatValue];
    float interest3 = [self.rateThree floatValue]/100;
    float power3 = powf((1+(interest3)), x);


    if (fieldEnum == CPTScatterPlotFieldX) {
        return [NSNumber numberWithInt:x];
    }
    else if(fieldEnum == CPTScatterPlotFieldY){
        if([plot.identifier isEqual:@"Investment #1"])
        {
            return [NSNumber numberWithFloat:principal1*power1];
        }
        else if([plot.identifier isEqual:@"Investment #2"])
        {
            return [NSNumber numberWithFloat:principal2 * power2];
        }
        else if([plot.identifier isEqual:@"Investment #3"])
        {
            return [NSNumber numberWithFloat:principal3 * power3];
        }
        else if ([plot.identifier isEqual:@"Placeholder"])
        {
            return [NSNumber numberWithFloat:0];
        }
    }
    return [NSNumber numberWithFloat:0];
}


- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning
{
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}


- (IBAction)foundSwipe:(id)sender {
    [self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];
}
@end
```

Am I missing something? Why is there a difference between my Xcode iPad simulator graph and the one that displays on my actual device? Any help or advice is welcome.

Comment: As I'm looking at my values in debug, I'm noticing that my properties are transferring properly on the simulator, but not on the device.  Is it possible that I'm not moving my data from one view controller to the next properly?

Comment: I'm using NSLog to check the values assigned to my GraphViewController's properties after the assignment statements at the top of the GraphViewController.m's -viewDidLoad method.  Only one value goes through each time and the rest are null. For example if I sent 11 for self.principal1 and 2 for self.rate1, self.principal1 = null and self.rate1 = 2.  The value that goes through is always the last one entered in the text field in the Data Scene.

Comment: Well, I got it to work. I changed the 'weak' attribute of my properties in my DataViewController.h file to 'strong'. Maybe this is a bad practice, but it works for now.  I'm still open to any info that others might have. Thanks!!!